# SQL Server 2005 How to filer data using alliance name of the field

Tags: sql-server-2005

I am using SQL Server 2005 and I want to filter data which contains one alliance name of the field but I can only short the data using the alliance variable of the field.

ex.

```
Select 
     (Select SName from StkMst Where SrNo = StkSrNo ) as StkName 
from  
     CmpMst 
Where 
     StkName like 'MR.'
```

If anyone can help me.........

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! I would recommend you to read http://tinyurl.com/sohints and try to improve your question.

Answer (score 0):

Use like this

```
Select StkName.SName from (Select SName from StkMst Where SrNo = StkSrNo ) StkName where StkName.SName like 'MR.%'
```

Also, rephrase your question a bit which will help to understand what you are exactly trying to achive.

Answer (score 0):

Basically, if the expression is complex and you don't want to repeat it in the WHERE clause, you should probably derive a table from that select and apply the filter to the outer query:

```
SELECT *
FROM (
  SELECT
    SomeColumn1,
    SomeColumn2,
    SomeExpression AS SomeAlias
  FROM SomeTable
)
WHERE SomeAlias = SomeValue
```

In your particular example the filter should probably be applied to the correlated query, like this:

```
SELECT
  (
    SELECT SName
    FROM StkMst
    WHERE SrNo = StkSrNo AND StkName LIKE 'MR.'
  ) AS StkName
FROM CmpMst
```